# How to run shell-commands in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, cmd, background

I made a remote-control client which can receive commands from the server. The commands that are received will be executed as normal cmd commands in a shell. But how can I execute these commands in the background so that the user wont see any in- or output.

For example when I do this, the user would see anything whats going on:

```
import os
os.system(command_from_server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using subprocess Popen to start a cmd without waiting for end:

```
from subprocess import Popen
pid = Popen(["ls", "-l"]).pid
```

Popen has a lot of configure options for handling stdout and stderr. See the ufficial doc.

Comment: I don't know subprocess Popen yet, but i will try it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To execute a command in background, you have to use the subprocess module.
For example:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("command", shell=True)
```

If you want to execute command with more than one argument eg: ls -a, the code is a bit different:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("ls -a", shell=True)
```

To change the directory you can use the os module:

```
import os
os.chdir(path)
```

But, as mentioned from tripleee in the comments bellow, you can also pass the cwd parameter to the subprocess.Popen-Method.

Comment: Thats not true; `subprocess` accepts a keyword argument `cwd=` where you can specify in which directory to run the subprocess.

Comment: Also, `shell=True` is wrong in the second example; you *either* pass `ls -l` as a single string, or (better. here) drop the `shell=True`.